# Populate signing config from bash

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am a bit newbie with grade and I am unclear on the following.
If I understand correctly the following:

```
android {  
    signingConfigs {  
        config {  
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']  
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']  
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])  
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']  
        }  
    }  
    ...  
  }
```

Creates an object with member fields `keyAlias` `keyPassword` etc.
So using the getter methods gradle can sign the app.
So if my understanding is correct how could I set these values if the actual value to populate the object with can be retrieved from an external bash function?
E.g. the `keyPassword` could be set from some `cat password_file|awk ‘{print $1}’`. This is just an example. I want to understand how would I populate the object the way I need

Comment: Where do you define `keystoreProperties`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice:That snippet is copy/paste from gradle docs. I was trying to understand how it works

Comment: Generally they can be referenced from a file which is not public.

Comment: @EmreAktürk:I am not asking about best practices. I am asking how to configure this object anyway that fits my needs

Comment: Please provide a link to the docs where you got this code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Answer (score -1):

You can define build types that uses signing configs but it's better to reference signingconfigs from a private file.

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file("keystore/keystore_debug")
        keyAlias 'xxx'
        keyPassword 'xxx'
        storePassword 'xxx'
    }
    release {
        storeFile file("keystore/keystore_release")
        keyAlias 'xxx'
        keyPassword 'xxx'
        storePassword 'xxx'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        zipAlignEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Now you can execute `./gradlew assemble` command to get a .apk file.

Comment: This does not answer my question in any way